# How do I give composer permission to create folders in var/www/html

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, permissions, composer-php

I am trying to create a laravel project with the command in Ubuntu 16.04

```
    composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

However, I am getting an error

```
    ErrorException mkdir(): permission denied.
```

I have read lots of resources about changing permissions but I have also read some that suggest that changing the folder permissions for /var/www/html is not good for security.

I want to know the proper and hence right way to allow composer access to create a laravel project within this directory. P.S I am coming from a windows development environment with minimal linux experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `chmod` command:

```
chmod -R 755 var/www/html
```

If you have access to the `root` user:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 var/www/html
```

Comment: does this not change the permissions? Im afraid that when I start developing then I might receive an error that I cannot write into the folder meaning ill have to change permissions yet again, and based on a number of resources thats not always a good idea.

Comment: @FrancisKisiara if you're not allowed to change permissions, I'm afraid you'll not be able to use Laravel on the machine.

Comment: Its my personal machine. I can change permissions. I used 755 but got the same error then I used 777 and it worked. This is what I was avoiding as I have read that that is a security hazard but nothing else seems to work.

Comment: Well, on the local machine you can use 777, just don't use it on a live server.

Comment: Oh! okay then. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

like @Alexey said
you can should change permission like above given commands but this you can also change ownership of var/www/html folder
here are the complete steps

1. First go to your www folder and right click and open terminal
2. on terminal you run these set of cammands

   ```
    sudo chown <Username> html/
   ```

   this command change owner ship of the folder

Answer (score 0):

on my personal machine I always use this command

`sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/html`

This command changes the ownership of the directory "/var/www/html" and all of its contents recursively to the currently logged-in user (represented by the "$USER" variable).For some reason `sudo chmod -R 755 var/www/html` does not work for me